# Will a 1950s television still work?

Tags: repair, tv

My company has a Philco Predicta television model H3407 as described here: [Philco Predicta description](http://www.radiolaguy.com/Showcase/VintageTV/PhilcoH3407C.htm). Will this TV still work with modern broadcasts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately, it won't. All of the analog broadcast signals that it was designed for are no longer transmitted; everything has been converted to digital.

The best you could do at this point is feed it a locally-generated signal via a cable from a suitable RF modulator.

Comment: Some converter boxes still have RF outputs.  I would expect one of those should work fine.

Comment: @supercat: Are there converter boxes that take a 16:9 1680 or 720 DVB-S/C/T HD signal and produce a cropped/letterboxed 4:3 NTSC signal?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Converters will typically have a control to select stretched/cropped/letterboxed mode.

Comment: Does this answer apply to the whole world or just the US?

Comment: @ThePhoton: The US and the EU, definitely. I'm not sure about the rest of the world.